# Render-server deploy failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I am trying to deploy a nodejs api to render i keep on getting deploy failed on the line

```
return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
```

[with this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au6OT.png)

My nodejs `package.json` [is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTwGW.png)

I ran the following command:

- `rm -rf node_modules/`
- `npm update`

My expected was to update the packages and let it deploy to live.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.